# How to create the approximately equal mark in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to create the approximately equal mark in the legend of the MATLAB. And it will show correctly, but when I try to export the plot by saveas (gca,'1.eps','psc2'). Then in the file, the approximately equal mark will be error code.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB legend(), title(), xlabel() and ylabel() functions interpret tex commands by default. A quick search suggests \approx or \cong as possible symbols to try. If it works, could you update your question with before and after examples?

This is what I have in mind

```
figure
title('Pi \approx 3.14')
```

or

```
title('Pi \cong 3.14')
```

See [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html#input_argument_namevalue_interpreter) for more details of MATLAB tex interpretation.

Comment: You are right, I also find it works just like in latex.